# Get Global Variable Value After Applying Function in Another Script

Tags: javascript, html, scope, global-variables

I have a variable initialized with no value in my first JavaScript file, let's call it first.js, like this: `var loggedInStatus;`

Then, in the `main` function of that JavaScript file, this variable is assigned a value like this: `loggedInStatus = true`

Lastly, in another JavaScript file, let's call this one second.js, I need to access this `loggedInStatus` variable with the value `true` assigned to it.

I understand the concept of loading first.js before second.js in the HTML files using script tags, but I'm wondering is there a way of passing over this associated true value as well as the loggedInStatus variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you can define `loggedInStatus` inside the global variable, you can access it.

for example,

```js
var loggedInStatus = 'j'; // global scope

(function(){ // a non-global scope
  
  loggedInStatus = true; // modifies the global scope variable;

})();

alert(loggedInStatus); // a global scope
```

You can use something like this, I always use it for my apps.

```
window.app = {};
```

`app` is an **global** object that can hold everything related to the app environment. I can defined modify, delete variables, objects, or functions.

```js
window.app = {};

console.log(app.loggedInStatus); // undefined

app.loggedInStatus = false; // set a variable;

console.log(app.loggedInStatus); // false;

app.loggedInStatus = true; // update;

console.log(app.loggedInStatus); // true;

delete app.loggedInStatus; // delete;

console.log(app.loggedInStatus); // undefined
```

Comment: Ok I understand the concept that you're offering as an answer, but could you please show me examples of how to implement this?